# How to get Content Type by Name or ID?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, content-type

I'm trying to get a Content Type by the Name or the ID.

I'm using this code but it does not work.

```
SPContentTypeId eventTypeId = new SPContentTypeId("0x0102"); 
SPContentType eventType = web.AvailableContentTypes[eventTypeId];
```

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Your code works for me and is the correct approach to load a SPContentType. What is the expception? What _does not work_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based On the the information you have provided in your question, I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
SPContentType spct = web.AvailableContentTypes ["ContentTypeName"];
```

Good luck! :)

Comment: `web.AvailableContentTypes` returns all content types in the current site collection. This has nothing to do with a web application.

Comment: thanks Stefan for your correction, Just before noticing your comment I realized that I was unsure about the correctness of my statement and omitted the whole paragraph since it seemed unnecessary anyway.

Comment: Plus, you might want to elaborate on your examples. They do not really explain, solve the issues from the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Just a note on the above. If you plan on making ANY changes to the content type then you don't want to use the above function. It will return read only versions. You want to be using:

```
web.ContentTypes["ContentTypeName"].
```

Instead of:

```
web.AvailableContentTypes["ContentTypeName"].
```

Just to save people a whole pile of time as the above answer is not really correct. It should include BOTH options as it really depends on the context and how they are using it. Although they don't give those sorts of details this is a top answer in google.

Comment: @JimYarbro Thanks I have done now ;-) did no know I could do that.